# Getting error ImportError: No module named slack_sdk.webhook

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python. I'm using PyCharm and Python Virtual Environment and following is a piece of import code which is throwing error. I checked my requirements.txt file and it has got slack library configured and then I ran pip3 install -r requirements.txt and executed my file python .py but getting below error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send_slack_notification.py", line 8, in <module>
    from slack_sdk.webhook import WebhookClient
ImportError: No module named slack_sdk.webhook
```

This is my code chunk:-

```
import argparse
import itertools
import json
import os

from slack_sdk.webhook import WebhookClient
from sonarqube import SonarQubeClient
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
```

requirements.txt:-

```
slack_sdk==3.19.4
Jinja2==3.1.2
python-sonarqube-api==1.3.0
python-gitlab==2.5.0
```

Please advise what mistake I'm doing it so that I take this as my learning, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5xU1.png)

like you can see in this picture... maybe is here the problem. When you create a new environment you need to choose the new python.exe inside of PYCHARM where you installed you library's. So...

Maybe you activate the Script on console, you are isntalling correct lib's in your env but you are opening your proyect pointing on C:....\Python.exe.

Find inside your env Script Folder with python.exe and select in Pycharm interpreter this Path.

Comment: thanks, @pamblo, interpreter was the culprit. I was able to configure it using the VirtualEnv